# How do I debug the System.Web assembly from Mono, if I already have the Microsoft System.Web assembly installed on my computer?

Tags: .net, debugging, mono

I need to debug a Mono assembly on my Windows x64 PC.

My first idea was just loading the assembly in .NET and using Visual Studio. The assembly is `System.Web`. The .NET version is on the GAC and is always loaded from there, maybe there's a way to circumvent that? Tried to uninstall from GAC and got a security/dependency error.

Also tried MonoDevelop with no luck. Cannot use MonoTools for VS because: 1- Won't pay for it, 2- I use VS Express (no plugins).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the original project with source code?  Open it in [Mono.](http://www.mono-project.com/Start)

Comment: @RobertHarvey What original project? it's `System.Web` from Mono that I need to debug.

Comment: Oh, you mean one of the Mono release assemblies.  As you know, Mono is an open-source project.  The complete source for every assembly is available for download.